# Repeat every character in a string N times

Tags: php

How can I get a string with each character of the string characters repeated by N times, in the same order as in the original string?

E.g., if I have `1010`, for N=2, I'd like to get `11001100`.

Or for `1234` and N=3, I'd like to get `111222333444`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$string = "1100";

echo repeatChars($string, 3);

// Output: 111111000000

function repeatChars($string, $times) {
    $output = '';
    $parts  = str_split($string);

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $output .= str_repeat($part, $times);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

For `abc` with `2` times you get  `aabbcc`

Answer (score 4):

Simplest is probably this for a fixed number of repetitions:

```
echo preg_replace('/(.)/', '$0$0', '1010');
```

Just fill in as many `$0` as the number of repetitions you want.

---

Or, for an variable number of repetitions:

```
$times = 3;
echo preg_replace('/(.)/', str_repeat('$0', $times), '1010');
```

Where `$times` holds the (numeric) number of repetitions you want.

Comment: And what about `n` times?

Comment: Well, you simply multiply the number of `$0` in the second argument. I extended the answer accordingly. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This is great! Though for converting short hex to long hex, this: `$hex = "#abc"; $hex = "#" . str_repeat(substr($hex, -3, 1), 2) . str_repeat(substr($hex, -2, 1), 2) . str_repeat(substr($hex, -1, 1), 2);` is a tad faster than this: `$hex = "#abc"; $hex = substr(preg_replace('/(.)/', '$0$0', $hex), 1);`

Comment: @ark the capture group  is not actually used, so you can remove it. https://3v4l.org/2acWU

Answer (score 0):

```
$str    = "1010";
$n      = 2;
$newStr = "";
for($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) {
        $newStr .= $str[$i];
    }
}   
echo $newStr;  //11001100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php
    $str = '1010';
    $times = 2;
    $str_len = strlen($str);
    $new_str = '';

    for($i=0; $i<$str_len; $i++) {
       $new_str .= str_repeat([$i], $times);
    }

    echo $new_str;
?>
```

*[str_repeat](http://php.net/str_repeat)*

Answer (score 0):

You have to explode your string to an array first. Then browse your table and repeat each character as you want.

```
<?php
    $val = 1010;
    $charToArray = str_split($val);
    for($x=0; $x<=count($charToArray); $x++) {
        for($y=1; $y<=2; $y++) { // repeat 2 times like your example
            echo $charToArray[$x];
        }
    }
?>
```